# Google Cloud SQL 5.7 - Tables in Database disappearing

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Recently we are finding rare issue with Cloud SQL 5.7 that clears the tables in our DB. This happened to couple of DB instances we have. We noticed this incident started on Thursday 2/13/2020, no changes have been made manually to delete the tables but the tables from the database have disappeared.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Have you contacted support?

Comment: Could you check the logs, table deletion is logged, and this way we can see what triggered caused this table to disapear.

Comment: Thanks for your comments i have contacted the support and yet to get a reply..

Comment: Hi Jose, i have gone through the logs but could not find any trace of deletion..perhaps i'm not looking at the right one. could you help?

Comment: I would advise you to check first on your instances' overview page under "operation & logs" for any activities their and then check from the activity tab of your project overview page, filtering by  "Resource type" to Cloud SQL Database for any lead you can provide us with.

Comment: Hi @bsivaram did you find the solution to this? We are also facing the same issue.